# Pearson's chi square test mathematical notation

Tags: statistics, notation

Is there any way to translate the statement below in full mathematical / symbolic notation without using any words? For example to rewrite it as a function f(A,E,x). If possible can someone show me how this can be written?

Given A and E containing actual and expected values of an experiment, with x degrees of freedom, if Pearson's chi square test rejects the null hypothesis at 0.05 significance level, then set i=1 else set i=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For degree of freedom $x$, the Density function of the chi-squared distribution is

$\large \frac{1}{2^{x/2}\Gamma(x/2)}t^{x/2-1}e^{-t/2}$

The Cumulative Density Function for chi-square distributed variate $y$ is

$\large \frac{1}{\Gamma(x/2)}\gamma(\frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{2})$

where

$\large \gamma(\frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{2}) = \int_0^{y/2}t^{x/2-1}e^{-t}dt$

For the chi squared test where $A_i$ is the actual result and $E_i$ is expected result, the test statistic is

$\large \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(A_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$

For the Null Hypothesis to be rejected at the $0.05$ level, we must have

$\large \frac{1}{\Gamma(x/2)}\gamma(\frac{x}{2},\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(A_i-E_i)^2}{E_i})>0.95$

or

$\large \frac{1}{\Gamma(x/2)} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(A_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}}t^{x/2-1}e^{-t}dt>0.95$

Now we want to set $i$ to 1 if the test is rejected, else we set $i$ to zero.

We can use the signed function $sgn(x)$, where

$\large sgn(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$

for non-zero $x$, and

$\large sgn(0)=0$

So that our final function is:-

$\large i=\frac{1}{2}[sgn((\frac{1}{\Gamma(x/2)}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(A_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}}t^{x/2-1}e^{-t}dt) - 0.95)+1]\times sgn((\frac{1}{\Gamma(x/2)} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(A_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}}t^{x/2-1}e^{-t}dt) - 0.95)$

The second signed function is needed to deal with the corner case where the integral is exactly $0.95$, resulting in $sgn(0)$, which equals $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Ahmed. Along the same lines would it mean that the notation below is correct as well? $$g_(_A_,_E_,_x_)=1-\frac{\gamma \left(\frac{x}{2},\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{(A_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}
,
f_(_A_,_E_,_x_)=\left\{\begin{matrix}g_(_A_,_E_,_x_)\geqslant 0.05 & \rightarrow 0 & \\ 
g_(_A_,_E_,_x_)<0.05 & \rightarrow 1 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: Yes, your notation is indeed correct. I have modified my answer, to take into account n observations as you have correctly done.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the mechanics of it. My notation doesn't seem to render well in Tex, trying to fix it now.

Comment: No problems, I hope you get the formatting sorted out. I copied your notation to a tex file and compiled it to a pdf to check your notation.